# Can't get an image from foursquare api, on swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icons, photo, foursquare

Im using das quadrat foursquare sdk for swift (QuadratTouch) 
everything works fine expect getting images
they marked in JSON like NSDictionary with "prefix" and "suffix"
and UIImage get nil in the end

Parsing JSON and creating a normal url

```
let parameters = [Parameter.ll:"\(lat),\(long)", Parameter.limit:"35", Parameter.radius:"\(radius)", Parameter.intent:"browse"]
    let currentTask = session.venues.search(parameters) {
        (result) -> Void in
        var places = [Place]()
        if let response = result.response {
            if let venues =  response["venues"] as? NSArray {
                for venue in venues {
                    if let categories = venue["categories"] as? NSArray {
                       let categoryInfo = categories[0] as! NSDictionary
                              if let  location = venue["location"] as? NSDictionary,
                                name = categoryInfo["name"] as? String,
                                address = location["address"] as? String,
                                lat = location["lat"] as? CLLocationDegrees,
                                long = location["lng"] as? CLLocationDegrees,
                                icon = categoryInfo["icon"] as? NSDictionary,
                                prefix = icon["prefix"] as? String,
                                suffix = icon["suffix"] as? String {
                                    let url = prefix + suffix
                                    let pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                                    places.append(FourSquarePlace(coordinates: pos, title: name, address: address, imageURL:url, photo: nil))
                            }
```

and image getting method from SessionAuthorizationDelegate

```
 self.session.downloadImageAtURL(NSURL(string: imageURL)!, completionHandler: { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                    //print(imageData)
                    print(imageURL)
                    if imageData != nil {
                        thisMarker.icon = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    }
                })
```

I've tried to paste the ULR from son to browser and got it

```
AccessDeniedAccess DeniedAF1DF956303F2D6EcRetLqGf3ipb6KOsSJ9YkqiDnmEUkjhEavefWCzjlHQAivKWMLsRMQukWsYiVCYK
```

i guess maybe it can't add Access Token to image, but its weird cause I'm usind sdk method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> let url = prefix + suffix

This usage is incorrect. You have to specify the size of image.

ex.

> let url = prefix + "100x100" + suffix

See also [Foursquare API document](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo.html)

> To assemble a resolvable photo URL, take prefix + size + suffix, e.g. https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/general/300x500/2341723_vt1Kr-SfmRmdge-M7b4KNgX2_PHElyVbYL65pMnxEQw.jpg.
>
> size can be one of the following, where XX or YY is one of 36, 100, 300, or 500.
>
> - XXxYY
> - original: the original photo's size
> - capXX: cap the photo with a width or height of XX (whichever is larger). Scales the other, - smaller dimension proportionally
> - widthXX: forces the width to be XX and scales the height proportionally
> - heightYY: forces the height to be YY and scales the width proportionally

Comment: THANK YOU! I was having the same exact problem and this solved the issue.